# Regular expression 00 or 11 not both

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Can anyone help me with this question: I know it before, but I have tried to solve it myself and didnt succeed.
what is the regular expression for this language: L=all words that have 00 or 11 but not both.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try constructing a DFA to recognize this language? That should help.

Comment: I constructed the dfa of the language that have 00, another dfa for the language that contain 11, using both i constructed the language that contain 11 or 00 but not both.
I tried converting that dfa to regular expression but it didnt work for me..maybe i did somthing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be the union of two languages:
$$ A = \mbox{All words that have 00 but not 11} $$
and
$$ B = \mbox{All words that have 11 but not 00} $$
A regular expression for a language that does *not* contain `11` can be of the form:
$$(1+\epsilon)(01+0)*$$
Therefore, a regular expression for A could be:
$$ (1+\epsilon)(01+0)* (00) (1+\epsilon)(01+0)* $$
And a regular expression for B could be similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answered
you realy helped me

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$. Then $L=L'\cup L''$ where

$$L' = \{w\in\Sigma^* : w\text{ has } 00, w\text{ does not have } 11 \}, $$
$$L'' = \{w\in\Sigma^* : w\text{ has } 11, w\text{ does not have } 00 \}. $$

A regular expression for $L'$ is

$$ (0(10)^* \cup 10(10)^*)(00^*\cup 00^*10^*),$$

and a regular expression for $L''$ is

$$ (1(01)^*\cup 01(01)^*)(11^*\cup 11^*01^*). $$

Hence a regular expression for $L$ is

$$ (0(10)^* \cup 10(10)^*)(00^*\cup 00^*10^*) \cup (1(01)^*\cup 01(01)^*)(11^*\cup 11^*01^*).$$

Comment: Thank you too for your answer, im sorry that i cant accept two answers but he commented first, and so i read his answer first